# only 10 result items returning to the page out of 250 items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a statement in my service class which returns all users in the database. I currently have 250 users but in IE, chrome, and FF i am only getting 10 users per page. What are the possible causes and how could this be changed.

```
public IEnumerable<Users> GetUsers(int sectionID)
    {
        var _user = DataBase.ProcsContext.GetRoster<Users>(sectionID, u => new Users
        {
            Name = UserColumnMap.Name(u),
            Email = UserColumnMap.Email(u)
        });
        return _user;
    }
```

**GetRoster**

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetRoster<T>(int sectionId, Func<IDataRecord, T> modelBinder, int resultsPerPage = 10, int pageNumber = 1)
        {
            //code
        }
```

Comment: What are you binding the results to on the View side of things?

Comment: Just for clarification, do you currently have "250 users" who all have the same `sectionID` value?

Comment: Why don't you debug your code. put a break point at  "return _user;" and see how many are returning. if " return _user;" has only 10 then check, if 250 users are mapped to same section Id you are passing?

Comment: @DavidTansey yes they all have the same sectionID. I using an api controller so i will post all related files

Comment: @HaBo i just did and the return is only returning 10 and all 250 users have the same sectionID.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `GetRoster`?

Comment: @DavidTansey guess that helped find where the 10 is coming from. I just updated my post.

Comment: @DavidTansey how can i change that safely so that it will get all - i am planning on implementing and infinite scroll and it seems this `10` is holding me back

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I would suggest that any 'scroller' widget is going to want to receive the data in less-than-100% 'chunks' (IOW results-per-page).  I'm betting that you want to put that `resultsPerPage` parameter to work for you in your use of 'InfiniteScroll'.

Comment: Here's a [blog post/tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-pagination/) that talks about **Infinite Scroll** ***Pagination*** and then indicates that Step 1 is to **Plan Your Pagination**.  I am only posting this to reinforce the pagination concept and the fact that I do not believe that you want to "GET ALL" users as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the possible causes

The answer to this is in the piece of code you abridged by `//code`. If you see what happens in there you'll probably notice the `Skip` and `Take` methods that are commonly used in *paging*: presenting records in chucks of a certain size. Now the default values of the page size and page number are `10` and `1`, respectively. So you always get the first 10 records when you call this method without the optional parameters.

> and how could this be changed

Call the method with the page size and page number you need.

And - I would improve this code by removing `= 10` and `= 1`. I think for a paging method default parameters are useless and deceptive. You should always be aware of the page number and page size you want to get. Following David Tansey's comments: it would not be a good idea to change this into a method that always returns *all* records.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetRoster` method has a default `resultsPerPage` value of 10.  Try changing this value when calling the method, like below:

```
public IEnumerable<Users> GetUsers(int sectionID)
{
    var _user = DataBase.ProcsContext.GetRoster<Users>(sectionID, u => new Users
    {
        Name = UserColumnMap.Name(u),
        Email = UserColumnMap.Email(u)
    },
    resultsPerPage: 250);
    return _user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using(dbContext context = new dbcontext())
{
    var results = (from u in context.Users
                   where u.sectionId == SectionId
                   select new {u.Name, u.Email}).toList();

    return results;
}
```

Comment: @Joe Thank you for the edit. I will make sure next time i write my answers with no spelling mistakes.